# 了解, 理解, 讲解 usage in the same sentence

Tags: vocabulary

This is from a native speaker:  完整讲解请至官网收看.

Would 了解 and 理解 be suitable to be used in place of 讲解?  for example:

完整了解请至官网收看

完整理解请至官网收看

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

1. `講解` as a verb means 'to explicate (with speech)', but both `了解` and `理解` tend to mean 'to comprehend'. Even their grammatical subject is different: teachers explain, whereas students learn and comprehend.
2. `講解` here is a noun that means 'explanation'. The sentence can be translated as: 'For explanation in full, please watch (the video) on (our) official website'. This is obviously not said from the viewpoint of a student, so `了解` and `理解` do not make any sense here.
3. Then why do all three have the character `解`? `解` means something like 'to solve', but in `講解` someone else is solving the problem on behalf of the person in doubt, because it is done via speech (`講`, to speak). Whereas in `了解` and `理解`, usually it is implied that the person in doubt solves the problem themself. (In classical Chinese, `了` means 'to understand', whereas `理` means 'principle; reason'.)

Answer (score 1):

No, neither 了解 nor 理解 fit the bill. Can't really think of a good substitute.

完整讲解视频请至官网收看。
complete lecture video please to official website watch
Please go to the/our official website to watch the complete video.

Answer (score 1):

讲 - 說明, 傳述; 解 - 解釋, 解答, the two words combined means "verbal explanation".

Both 了解 and 理解 mean "understand", which is the ability to comprehend the nature or meaning of a message perceive mentally, no matter the form of the message was delivered.